# I have a function to generate random string,I want it to generate more than 1 line of random string

Tags: php, random

I have a Function to generate random string ,it produce more than 1 random string ,but how to separate them

```
    Function generatorstring($count) {

    $karakter = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $length = 7;
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i=0; $i <$count ; $i++) { 

        for ($ia = 0; $ia < $length; $ia++) {
            $randomString .= $karakter[rand(0, strlen($karakter) - 1)];
        }

    }

    return $randomString ;
}
echo generatorstring(3);
```

I expected result like this

```
'As6s8Xs',
'zE71jnM', 
'ak9a71b',
```

But, its only produce 1 line of random string.

Comment: You just keep appending to the same string, where do you expect the array?  Also worth noting, you can't echo an array.

Comment: `$randomString[]  = ...`

Comment: sorry forget the array, i mean it have to produce more than 1

Comment: @dWinder i still try it ,but it keep produce 1 line

Comment: Did you try using the last function with `print_r`?

Comment: A function can only return once. Even inside a loop, `return` ends it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate your code for function creating random string and then call it 3 times.

Separating code to small function doing simple action is basic for good practice programming.

Consider:

```
function generatorstring($length = 7){
    $karakter = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $karakter[rand(0, strlen($karakter) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

And now just call it as:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) 
    $res[] = generatorstring();
```

Or create a function who create array of random strings as:

```
function createRandomStringArray($count) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
        $res[] = generatorstring();
    return $res;
}
```

And then you can print the `$res` array using `print_r` or another loop

Answer (score 1):

Well, right off the bat, your biggest problem is that you have a for loop using a variable that is inside a for loop using the same variable.

First for loop establishes $i as 0, incrementing 1. Second for loop (inside) overwrites $i as 0 and increments until $i equals $length. $i is now 7. Outer for loop sees $i is 7, which is greater than $count (3), therefore the outer for loop breaks.

```
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   for($ia=0; $ia < $length; $ia++){
      //do something
   }
}
```

Also note, this is ugly, and it is better, as @dWinder mentioned, to put your inner for loop in its own function.

Comment: Nice catch - I didn't even notice that (answering from phone is hard to go by...)

Comment: thank you its done mister ,but the result is not split up

Comment: its generate 3 random string ,but how to split them ,i've using <br/> but not separate,its just like 1 line

Comment: @KhadamIkhwanus you would need to add more code before/after the inner `for` loop if you want to add line breaks, put it in quotes, etc. Your code is simply adding 3 sets of 7 characters to a single string. E.g. `$randString .= "<br />";` after the inner `for` loop.

Comment: thankyou mister @JacobS,i don't think about .= before